# WinSock closesocket() call takes one second on some computers

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, closesocket

This call should return after only a very short time, but on some machines it inexplicably takes very close to 1 second.  Has anyone seen this issue.  I am using the loopback address so the network should be out of the picture.

Comment: Perhaps anti-virus / firewall software is interfering?

Comment: Not very useful antivirus / firewall software if it just adds a delay.  I have my firewall turned off and no resident shield running for virus checker.  Same behaviour.

Comment: Some AV and security products have a tendency to introduce buggy behaviour.  If you're otherwise stuck, it might be worth uninstalling them all - while off the network, of course! - to double-check.

Comment: By the same token, of course, the problem might be that the machines in question are infected with some form of malware.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably somewhere inside the window sockets implementation. From the OS perspective calling `closesocket` (or `CloseHandle`) equivalent to releasing driver's "device" object. Mostly drivers process this request immediately (synchronously), aborting all the (potential) outstanding I/Os if necessary. However "silly" drivers may block you until *something* is completed.

That's what I'd do:

- Try to terminate your program (by task manager). Does it take time to terminate it? (if so - seems it's locked by the driver).
- If you're talking about stream socket (i.e. TCP or similar) - try to use `SO_DONTLINGER` option. That is, specify that you don't want to wait until all the pending data is sent to the peer.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell if it takes 1 second to terminate the process using the task manager since there are other delays.  SO_DONTLINGER shouldn't have any effect in this particular case, because no data is being sent over the socket, it just gets established and then closed down.  SO_DONTLINGER is for waiting until all data is sent.

Comment: @Jesse Pepper: Apart from sending an unsent data, in TCP there's a "ceremony" of closing a connection gracefully, which includes some ping-pong with `FIN` packets. I'm not sure, but maybe `SO_DONTLINGER` includes this as well. I.e. with this flag it aborts the connection with `RST`